# Swift debugQuickLookObject Xcode 12.4

Tags: swift, debugging

I'm trying to test `debugQuickLookObject` I'm using Xcode 12.4 but the sample code given doesn't return a String in the QuickLook Debugger or the console, is `debugQuickLookObject` still valid?

```
class User {
  var name = "Duane Dibbley"
  var age = 28

  @objc func debugQuickLookObject() -> Any? {
    return "My name is \(name) and I'm \(age)."
  }
}
```

I've tried inheriting from `NSObject` - no joy, I can't even confirm if the method signature is correct :-s

Code from here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-create-quick-look-debug-previews-for-your-custom-types

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the code working, but only for iOS based projects, code can be found here:

https://github.com/nthState/RealityKitDebugger

I wish I knew why macOS based projects don't work as expected.